# How do I stream a webcam from a raspberry Pi over WebRTC without opening a browser?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc

In a client to client situation I would use Chrome's navigator APIs to get a MediaStream and add its tracks to my RTCPeerConnection.

But I would prefer not opening a chrome window on my raspberry Pi to do this.

Are there any easy-to-use bindings in python or node JS to get a MediaStream and send it to a WebRTC peer?

Comment: I recently tried this step by step guide to build a low-cost vehicle surveillance using Raspberry Pi and WebRTC. This is helpful you can look into this. Here is the link:https://insights.enablex.io/how-to-guide-to-develop-smart-solutions-with-raspberry-pi-and-enablex-live-video-api/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to use webrtc without your own customization, you can try [uv4l](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l) or [rpi-webrtc-streamer](https://github.com/kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer). They provide webrtc solution with built in signalling over websockets. 
If you want to use webrtc but your own signalling, you can do proxy over inbuilt signalling. Other solutions like [AIORTC](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) or Node PeerConnection or node-webrtc May not be that much easy to use/configure.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would rather be the [chrome driver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) which can be run headless (mainly used for automated UI testing). You can start the browser by the command-line and give it some arguments like `--headles` and more. Pretty sure there are some nice libraries within python to do so. But maybe that's a wrong approach here.

So there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569445/webrtc-without-a-browser) already asked, where different approaches where suggested.

> If you want a Python implementation of WebRTC, give [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) a try. It features support for audio, video and data channels and builds upon Python's [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) framework.

But maybe check out the answers there, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Alohacam](https://alohacam.io) will do what you're looking for. Uses WebRTC to provide a real-time stream from your Raspberry Pi camera to any web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge, iOS, and Android). Also includes TURN support (no need to bring your own TURN relay). If you don't mind a closed-source solution that "just works", it may help. (full disclosure: I'm one of the authors -- would love to hear how it works out for you).

Comment: That's quite awesome, but are there any settings to control resolution, bitrate, etc.? Any plans on opening the source? Thanks!

Comment: The library and client are already open source. https://github.com/lanikai/alohartc.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like it won't build due to a repo that is no longer accessible. I added an issue to track it here - https://github.com/lanikai/alohartc/issues/118

Comment: Responded to the issue. tl;dr is you'll need to build your own signaling service.

Comment: @thinkski Warning! Alohacam.io is a phishing site now. Do not follow that link.

Comment: Good to know -- I didn't renew the domain name